# How should I re-caulk my butcher block counter top?

Tags: tile, caulking, kitchen-counters

Last year I had my kitchen re-done. Everything thus far has held up well with the exception of the [caulk between the counter top](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/269/imag0048cp.jpg/) (butcher-block) and the back splash (tile).

What would be the best way to remove the existing caulk? In addition is there a specific caulk I should use for this scenario? The contractor did a thin line however that separated within weeks. When I attempted to put a larger bead in the crack it was spread more then I desired onto the counter top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok Aaron, you will need to remove as much of the old caulk using a sharp putty knife. If you are careful you will not scratch the block or tile, however it can be tricky. Alternately, a rigid plastic scraper or caulk removal tool (cheap at HI stores) can be used to assure no scratching or gouging. The next step is to run a line of 3M delicate surface painter's tape in a very straight line down the counter top and along the back splash exactly where you want the caulk to end. Select a 100% silicone caulking of the color you want. Apply an even bead of caulk to the seam, smooth it with your finger or a plastic tool tapering the edge thinly at the edge of the tape. Work quickly, do not let the caulking start to set up. As soon as you are happy with the bead's smoothness, remove the tape immediately.  Let the caulk set up and cure for 24 hours before exposing it to water.  Good luck.

Comment: +1; also, here's a link to a forum thread about caulking with pictures that show this method: http://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=85634

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an oil (Tung) finish on your countertop rather than poly, I suspect silicon will not adhere well. Though I'm facing the same issue as you, and have not tackeled it yet, I'm planning on trying a Poly calk like Lexel. I should imagine the most obvious choice wood be a maritime deck calk.

R